# What does the "p" and "01" icons signify in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I wrote a simple Java program in IntelliJ IDEA and added some breakpoints to checkout the stack frames and the respective variables of the stack frames as shown in the image below:

[image]

In the Variables panel for the "main" stack frame, there are 2 symbols - "p" (in yellow circle) and "01" (in blue square).

What is the meaning of these symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for this variables panel is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/examining-suspended-program.html#variable-types)

p means method parameters

01 means local primitive types

Go to the linked documentation page and click on "Variable types":
[image: click on Variable types expands the list]

Comment: Can you elaborate the process as I can’t find any info in the doc

Comment: See updated answer